# Lost mouse pointer in XServer

Tags: debian, mouse, x-server

Have tried many windows managers including TWM, xfce and Gnome, but my mouse pointer is gone. It is invisible, but it performs all the actions. If I do the right click the context menu opens and this is how I can tell what the current location of the pointer is.

This is a newest stable built of Debian.

How can I restore the mouse pointer?

The output from lsmod is included below.
Links

[to Xserver logs](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1pCRtPenb5KPhesS_MeAFHQ_-iMeaWB9pppWezlFiyUA) and

[dmesg output](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1gUWYlwJc5CshFqm1iC5NPm02CWs403D1JdQDRzqSAjk).

Can anybody help?

UPDATE:
It does indeed work well with the 2.6.38 kernel.

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8                 908  1 
nls_cp437               4489  1 
vfat                    6570  1 
fat                    34912  1 vfat
usbhid                 28008  0 
hid                    50909  1 usbhid
cpufreq_conservative     4018  0 
cpufreq_userspace       1480  0 
cpufreq_powersave        602  0 
cpufreq_stats           1940  0 
ppdev                   4058  0 
lp                      5570  0 
sco                     5857  2 
bridge                 33019  0 
stp                      996  1 bridge
bnep                    7444  2 
rfcomm                 25175  0 
l2cap                  21709  4 bnep,rfcomm
bluetooth              36319  6 sco,bnep,rfcomm,l2cap
binfmt_misc             4907  1 
fuse                   44256  1 
ext4                  257803  1 
jbd2                   56155  1 ext4
crc16                   1027  2 l2cap,ext4
loop                    9765  0 
firewire_sbp2           9647  0 
snd_intel8x0           19595  0 
snd_ac97_codec         79148  1 snd_intel8x0
arc4                     974  4 
ecb                     1405  4 
ac97_bus                 710  1 snd_ac97_codec
rt2500pci              11303  0 
snd_pcm_oss            28671  0 
rt2x00pci               3773  1 rt2500pci
snd_mixer_oss          10461  1 snd_pcm_oss
ath5k                 104074  0 
rt2x00lib              19101  2 rt2500pci,rt2x00pci
ath                     6014  1 ath5k
snd_pcm                47226  3 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss
i915                  223024  2 
mac80211              123570  3 rt2x00pci,ath5k,rt2x00lib
snd_seq_midi            3576  0 
cfg80211               87657  4 ath5k,rt2x00lib,ath,mac80211
snd_rawmidi            12513  1 snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         18309  1 i915
snd_seq_midi_event      3684  1 snd_seq_midi
rfkill                 10264  3 bluetooth,cfg80211
eeprom_93cx6             963  1 rt2500pci
drm                   112088  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_seq                35463  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
pcmcia                 16194  0 
snd_timer              12258  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i2c_algo_bit            3497  1 i915
snd_seq_device          3673  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
yenta_socket           16403  3 
rsrc_nonstatic          7057  1 yenta_socket
asus_laptop            11090  0 
pcmcia_core            20450  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,rsrc_nonstatic
i2c_i801                6462  0 
parport_pc             15799  1 
joydev                  6739  0 
led_class               1757  3 ath5k,rt2x00lib,asus_laptop
parport                22554  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
i2c_core               12787  5 i915,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit,i2c_i801
snd                    34375  9 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 21220  0 
evdev                   5609  13 
video                  14605  1 i915
battery                 3782  0 
processor              26327  1 
button                  3598  1 i915
ac                      1640  0 
rng_core                2178  0 
output                  1204  1 video
pcspkr                  1207  0 
soundcore               3450  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          5045  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
psmouse                44809  0 
serio_raw               2916  0 
pci_hotplug            18065  1 shpchp
ext3                   94204  1 
jbd                    32169  1 ext3
mbcache                 3762  2 ext4,ext3
usb_storage            30833  1 
sd_mod                 26005  6 
crc_t10dif              1012  1 sd_mod
8139too                14949  0 
ata_generic             2067  0 
ata_piix               17736  3 
uhci_hcd               16057  0 
firewire_ohci          16725  0 
thermal                 9206  0 
8139cp                 13421  0 
libata                115753  2 ata_generic,ata_piix
ehci_hcd               28681  0 
firewire_core          31243  2 firewire_sbp2,firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t               1035  1 firewire_core
thermal_sys             9378  3 video,processor,thermal
mii                     2714  2 8139too,8139cp
usbcore                98733  5 usbhid,usb_storage,uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd
nls_base                4541  5 nls_utf8,nls_cp437,vfat,fat,usbcore
scsi_mod              101429  4 firewire_sbp2,usb_storage,sd_mod,libata
```

Comment: What changed between the time you had a mouse pointer and the time it went away (especially system upgrades)? Have you tried starting a new X server (log out, press `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`) or even rebooting?

Comment: It is a fresh install of latest stable Debian, replacing Fedora I had for a a few years. Have tried all of that, but the pointer is still invisible.

Comment: If possible, try a more recent kernel. 2.6.38 is in unstable, and should install and boot on stable. And it is not hard to rebuild on stable if necessary. If you are using proprietary drivers or building out of kernel modules, that could make it more difficult. Also, please report the bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be affected by a bug in the `i915` driver on the 852GM chip family. There are patches available, but it seems that they may cause other bugs on some chips. A workaround that works for some people is to suspend and resume.

- [Freedesktop bug #29413: [855GM bisected] Mouse cursor invisible since kernel 2.6.35](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29413)
- [Debian bug #619019: xserver-xorg-video-intel: latest update to debian squeeze made the mouse pointer invisible in my openbox/gdm session](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619019)
- [Ubuntu bug #642283: [852gm] invisible mouse cursor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/642283)

Comment: This issue seems to pop up here on arch linux with a current xf86-video-intel 1:2.99.917+772+gc72bb27a-1 (i915, ) and linux 4.11.3. Interestingly, the workaround of suspend&resume still works! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try running this command in a terminal:

```
xsetroot -cursor_name X_cursor
```

It should set the default cursor to an X.  You should have a list of possible cursors under `/usr/share/icons/whiteglass/cursors`.  If that doesn't exist, try `ls -ld /usr/share/icons/*/cursors`  One of my favorite cursors is trek.

```
xsetroot -cursor_name trek
```

Comment: Thanks, but still invisible

Answer (score 3):

If anyone stumbles upon this question nowadays reason might be debian [bug:#755050](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755050), which can be worked around by (see debian bugtracker for details):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor/active false
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in this [Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/682345/315347). A missing mouse pointer in Debian Gnome might also be solved by entering "mouse" in the launcher. This starts the mouse and touchpad settings dialogue and the mouse appears again.