# Fedora19 -- Mouse pointer suddenly disappears

Tags: x11, gnome3, mouse, fedora

I'm running a desktop machine with Fedora19, Gnome3, dual monitors (30" left, 27" right).

Once in a while my mouse pointer disappears from the primary screen.  If I move the mouse to the secondary screen, it appears and moves normally but as a garbled icon that looks like this:

[image: garbled mouse pointer]

This happens at random times right in the middle of me working.  Although it seems to happen usually when I move the mouse around (e.g. to change focus to another window) rather than when I'm typing on the keyboard.  In any case, it isn't due to the system going on suspend or hibernate like in other similar questions.

When that happens, so far I haven't found any way to restore the mouse pointer.  I found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12670/31177) an idea on how to set the pointer to some other icon and I'll be sure to try that next time it happens.  But up until now, even switching user, or logging out and re-logging in doesn't change the situation: invisible mouse on the 30" screen and garbled one on the 27".  Not knowing any better solution, I have to reboot.

Any ideas?

Links:

- [output of lsmod](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/810942ca6cf12e61a66a#file-lsmod)
- [excerpt of /var/log/messages around the time the pointer gets nuked and up to reboot](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/810942ca6cf12e61a66a#file-_var_log_messages)
- [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/810942ca6cf12e61a66a#file-_var_log_xorg-0-log)
- [output of dmesg after reboot](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/810942ca6cf12e61a66a#file-dmesg_ok)

Other info:

```
# uname -a
Linux evian 3.14.7-100.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 11 22:34:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation P67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730 GL [FirePro V3750]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
03:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9123 PCIe SATA 6.0 Gb/s controller (rev 11)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01)
06:02.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
07:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
09:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller (rev 10)
```